# Why does server process multiple clients at the same time when it's not multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, udp

So in my code below i have a singlethreaded server and a multithreaded client. The reason for this is because i want the client to send packets and receive packets simultaneously. However when i start the server and run multiple clients the server can process multiple clients simultaneously even tough the server is not multithreaded? Can you explain this?

Server:

```
public class server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    new server();
}


//declare the UDP server socket
DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
int port = 3741;

public server() throws IOException {
    
    //create UDP server with a specific port number
    datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    System.out.println("[UDP server] Datagram socket started on port " + port);
    
    //prepare the packet structure for received packets
    int dataLength = 100; //must be large enough so some part of packet doesn't get lost
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[dataLength];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    
while(true) {
        datagramSocket.receive(packet);
        System.out.println("client connected");
        
        InetAddress inetAddress = packet.getAddress();
        int clientPort = packet.getPort();
        byte[] data = packet.getData();

        
        
        //send response back to the client host
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        
        DatagramPacket datagramPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, inetAddress, clientPort);
        datagramSocket.send(datagramPacket); //sending data from server to client
        
}
}

}
```

Client:

```
public class client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new client();
}


public client() throws Exception{
    
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
    String message = "hello from client"; 
    
    DatagramPacket packetSend = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.getBytes().length, ip, 3741);
    
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                try {
                    socket.send(packetSend);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            
        }
    });
    th.start();
    
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    
    //this part can't be in a thread because the loop above us will finish first before this starts
    //we can put this code before the loop and start a thread this would also work
    while(true) {
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        String data = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
        
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: "the server can process multiple clients simultaneously" - please edit the question to be more specific - what exactly are you seeing that doesn't make sense to you? interleaved prints from different clients, one for each request?

Answer (score 2):

You think *"the server can process multiple clients simultaneously even tough the server is not multithreaded"* cause your brain cheat you. Acutually they are processing one by one in a reliatively fast speed. It's easy to see if you use wireshark or tcpdump to capture the server side packets. You will find the interesing truth.

Comment: I put thread.sleep() in server and it showed how each client is being processed one by one. No need to install applications for this use. It can be done more easy that way.

Comment: If you want to go deep into network programming, you must need wireshark and tcpdump one day.

Comment: I am a full stack web developer for me there is no need to go extremely deep into any kind of specific subject.